# Getting ids for the hasMany relationship from Laravel 5.6 Form to the Controller

Tags: php, laravel-5.6, laravelcollective

I am trying to get the ids for the four answers for a single question from a Laravel Edit form.

Here is my form view blade code:

```
@php $i=0; @endphp
    @foreach($question->answers as $answer)
    @php $i++; @endphp
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
        {!!Form::label('Answeroption'.$i, 'Answeroption'.$i)!!}
        {!! Form::text('answeropt'.$i,$answer->answeropt, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id' => $answer->id]) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

I want to get this **'id'=> $answer->id** in the QuestionController, Edit method. This piece of code is in the question edit form with 4 answer options. Each answer is stored in answer table with different its id linked to the main question id. I want to get this answerid,so that I can store the edited answers.

I tried to do getIdAttribute but it is not working.

Here is the screenshot of how my screen looks. Each option has an entry in answer table with question_id linked to it as HasMany relationship.

Screenshot of the Edit Question Form

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better off using an array in your markup. Then you will have the ids to reference upon post. So this might look something like:

```
{!! Form::text('answeropt['. $answer->id . ']',$answer->answeropt, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id' => $answer->id]) !!}
```

Then in your controller, you can loop over the array and utilize the id. So that might look something like:

```
foreach($request->get('answeropt', []) as $answerId => $answer) {
    // do things with the answer id and the answer text
}
```

I think this is what you are after? Please let me know if this is clear, or if you meant something else.

Comment: Yes, Thanks Bryan! This was very useful.